# Como converto LINQ em SQL para o MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, linq

Estou tentando remover o uso de instruções SQL de dentro do sistema (para torná-lo flexível quanto ao banco que será usado), uso instruções `Insert`, `Update` e `Delete` via *stored procedure* (pelo de desempenho e pela flexibilidade), mas ainda uso instruções SQL para as consultas pois se transforma-las em *stored procedures* vou ter que criar várias *procedures* para cada tabela do sistema.

Então como posso converter uma instrução LINQ qualquer em um SQL para MySQL?

Comment: O LINQ to SQL e o Entity Framework fazem isso por você. Qual a necessidade de alterar um esquema que funciona para qualquer banco de dados para um esquema que funciona em um só?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelos comentários deu para entender (eu acho) que você quer deixar de usar SQL para usar o LINQ.

Além de tudo o que o Vinícius disse, você não deve fazer isso se você quer a possibilidade de usar vários bancos de dados diferentes. Talvez a mais notória limitação do LINQ To SQL é justamente em não poder trabalhar com diversos bancos.

Se esta é sua intenção deve criar um mecanismo próprio ou usar algum pronto que abstraia as diferenças entre os diversos bancos.

Não vou dizer que recomendo mas você deveria dar uma olhada no [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework), este é o [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) que é recomendado pela Microsoft em casos assim. Na página da Wikipedia tem uma lista de outras opções como o [NHibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) que ainda também tem razoável utilização.

Não é tão fácil aprender usá-los mas deve dar o resultado que você espera.

Não conheço estes produtos o suficiente para lhe dizer se é fácil trabalhar com *stored procedures* da maneira como você pretende usando estas tecnologias.

Com o EF é possível usar o LINQ mas no modelo LINQ To Entities.

Se preferir algo mais simples e puder continuar lidando com SQL pode dar uma olhada no [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). Em geral eu prefiro caminhos mais simples. Mas é claro que neste caso tem que saber como trabalhar com os diversos bancos sem causar confusão. Eu particularmente acho mais fácil fazer desta forma mas a maioria dos programadores acham que é mais fácil deixar um *framework* pronto lidar com isto.

Reforço a ideia já relatada por outros que *stored procedure* não é uma boa ideia para o que você deseja. Muito menos vai trazer os benefícios que está relatando que terá. Eu diria que provavelmente trará resultado contrário em algumas situações.

Answer (score 6):

Stored procedure não possue ganho de desempenho significativo para operações de CRUD, a não ser que você esteja fazendo agregações de dados e manipulações complexas que envolveriam muitos "ir e vir" entre sua aplicação e o DB.

Store procedures também não aumentam flexibilidade, uma vez que cada RDBMS possui sintaxe diferente, causando a reescrita as vezes até total da procedure.

Como você não postou código algum, recomendo que leia o beginner's guide da própria Microsoft sobre o assunto:

[Beginner's Guide to LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff728653.aspx)

**Edição**

Para utilizar LINQ com MySql, acredito que sua única opção seja o pacote LinqConnector, que inclusive suporta outros RDBMS além do MySQL. Ele está disponível no NuGet para instalação ou no endereço:

[LinqConnect Express](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3aba2a36-ad47-4cd8-a514-873edc30a239)

Comment: Concordo plenamente que procedures não agregam em desempenho ou flexibilidade para CRUD. Com exceção de processamentos *batch* ou relatórios complexos, são raríssimas as ocasiões onde isso seria recomendado. Colocar mais camadas em um sistema sempre dificulta o desenvolvimento e a manutenção, só compensando quando isso trouxer um ganho real em outro aspecto.

Comment: Eu sei que terei de reescrever as procedures para DBs diferentes, porem a chamada das procedures entro da aplicação sera a mesma por isso a flexibilidade. Quando a postar algum código quero salientar que estou perguntando pela metodologia a ser aplicada, se é possível ou não, eu não tentei fazer essa conversão e obtive um erro, eu se quer encontrei como faze-la por isso estou perguntando "... como posso converter uma instrução LINQ qualquer em um SQL para MySQL?"

Comment: Existem ferramenta free que fazem isso, uma delas é o LINQPad. Eu utilizo aqui procedures e bastante(tudo com elas) mas a garantia da empresa é que vai usar o sql server "eternamente". Agora eu prefiro reescrever do que ficar traduzindo de uma lado para outro. Essas ferramentas geram muito "lixo". Pelo que entendi existe LINQ no seu projeto e você quer passar para SQL, certo? Ou é o contrário, que pela pergunta entendo ser assim como escrevi.

Comment: Eu utilizo SQL e quero mudar para LINQ, porem ate onde vi o LINQ pode atuar sobre uma coletânea de objetos, uma Lista tipada por exemplo, ou consultando registros no SQL Server porem eu não vi como usar o LINQ em bancos MySQL, por isso perguntei sobre a conversão. Até por que achava que seria um recurso nativo do próprio C#, se tiver que recorrer a ferramentas de terceiros, prefiro reescrever as consultas como você opnou.

Comment: Adicionei informações sobre o pacote que deve ser utilizado para utilizar LINQ com MySQL.

Comment: Continuando... Eu encontrei uma pergunta sobre a diferença de velocidade entre sproc e EF no Stackoverflow em inglês, deem uma olhada. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739230/entity-framework-vs-stored-procedures-performance-measure

Comment: @BenjamimMendesJunior Você esta comparando duas coias diferentes. Entity Framework é um ORM. Stored Processure é um recurso para realização de consultas complexas dentro do Banco de Dados. O Entity Framework é lento porque ele funciona navegando por um grafo de objetos, e realiza muitas requisições individuais para completar uma ação muitas vezes simples. Particularmente, sou contra a utilização de ORM na grande maioria dos casos (especialmente nos que precisam de velocidade).